# How to programmatically identify where n would fit in this sequence?

Tags: javascript, math, sequence

I have a number I want to conform to the closest value in the following sequence:

`2, 5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 22, 25, 29, 32, 35, 39, 42...`

If `10` is passed, it would become `12`, `13` would become `15`, `17` would become `19`.

How would I approach this in a function?

Comment: I hope this isn't actually really obvious, but... what's the sequence? Is it just an array?

Comment: It's not an array, I just want to conform the number to the sequence function.

Comment: `17` is as close to `15` as it is to `19`, so this is somehow ambiguous - and `10` is closer to `9` than to `12`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @LeviMcCallum: So... what's the sequence function? I've posted a generic solution for now, assuming `f(x)` grows as `x` grows.

Comment: @schnaader Apologies, the former is a bad example. The latter, however, since it is already in the next multiple of 10, needs to round to the next highest value.

Comment: @minitech WolframAlpha has a clearer example on the sequence function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2C+5%2C+9%2C+12%2C+15%2C+19%2C+22%2C+25%2C+29%2C+32%2C+35%2C+39. Apparently it would look something like `(2 + 3 * z + 4 * Math.pow(z, 2) + Math.pow(z, 3))/(Math.pow((-1 + z), 2) * (1 + z + Math.pow(z, 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether the array is sorted, you could use code like this to find the value in the array that is the closest to the passed in value (higher or lower):

```
var list = [2, 5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 22, 25, 29, 32, 35, 39, 42];

function findClosestValue(n, list) {
    var delta, index, test;
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        test = Math.abs(list[i] - n);
        if ((delta === undefined) || (test < delta)) {
            delta = test;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return(list[index]);
}
```

If you want the closest number without going over and the array is sorted, you can use this code:

```
var list = [2, 5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 22, 25, 29, 32, 35, 39, 42];

function findClosestValue(n, list) {
    var delta, index;
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        delta = n - list[i];
        if (delta < 0) {
            return(index ? list[index] : undefined);
        }
        index = i;
    }
    return(list[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsFiddle with a solution that works for an infinite series of the combination "+3+4+3+3+4+3+3+4+3+3+4....." which seems to be your series. http://jsfiddle.net/9Gu9P/1/ Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

After looking at your answer I noticed you say you want the closes number in the sequence but your examples all go to the next number in the sequence whether it is closest or not compared the the previous number so here is another jsfiddle that works with that in mind so you can choose which one you want :).

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gu9P/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextInSequence(x){
    //sequence=2, 5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 22, 25, 29, 32, 35, 39, 42
    var i= x%10;

    switch(i){
        case 2:case 5:case 9: return x;
        case 0:case 1: return x+ 2-i;
        case 3:case 4: return x+5-i;
        default: return x+9-i;
    }
}
```

alert(nextInSequence(10))